# Load view into a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any way that I can get content of a PHP file in to variable?

I want to do this

```
$msg = $this->load->view('some_view');
```

but when I do this, `$msg` is `NULL`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It is possible:

```
$msg = $this->load->view('some_view', '', true);
```

Comment: can we pass any parameter variable to edit the view dynamically?

Comment: Yes, in the second parameter: `$this->load->view('some_view', $data, true);`

Comment: @YanBerk when i try to display the returned view like so: 
`die("<pre>" . print_r(array($lmsg), true) . "</pre>");` the page renders normally and won't display as a string (also tried a simple `var_dump($msg)` - same result). how can i get it to display as a string?

Comment: I eventually used `htmlentities()` like so:  `die("<pre>" . print_r(array(htmlentities($msg)), true) . "</pre>");`

Answer (score 14):

There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
$msg = $this->load->view('some_view', '', true);
```

Source : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', TRUE);
```

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data