# Codeigniter about passing data named subview variable from controller view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am following the tutorial and i have stuck with this problem. 
I get this error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: subview

Filename: admin/_layout_main.php

Line Number: 44
```

In tutorials controller it shows the code below about the subview

```
public function index() {

        $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
    }
```

The problem is when trying to use the data users and subviews into a view. As you can see subviews has a location of another view file, and call subviews in the main view like this from the tutorial:

```
<div class="span9">
        <?php $this->load->view($subview); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);// pass data like this from function index()

Comment: public function index() {

        $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
    } 
i already did

Comment: place $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data); instead of $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data); and use $subview in view page

Answer (score 1):

Plan B:

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();
    $this->data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/user/index');
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $subview; ?>
```

I'm grasping at straws here. I use the Stencil template system for CI. So much easier.

Comment: thesame sir, nothing happens

Comment: @Joe You would need to pass `TRUE` as the second parameter for the sub-view construction otherwise it'll be immediately printed.

Comment: That's true, Mackie. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows in  `controller`

```
public function index() {
        $this->load->model('user_m');

        $data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();
        $data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
    }
```

In `view` file .

```
<div class="span9">
        <?php echo  $subview ; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: U are loading the view again in your view. Trying echoing the $subview as told by @joe

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your view:

```
<div class="span9">
        <?php echo $subview; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Also try echoing whether you are actually getting the data from your model ?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: subview

Filename: admin/_layout_main.php

Line Number: 44

Comment: What are you trying to do with this statement ?
$data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index'; 

loading a view ? in a variable ?

Comment: Check this link to load the view in a variable :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772651/load-view-into-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

**controller**

```
public function index() {
        $data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();
        $data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
    }
```

**view**

```
<?php echo $subview; ?>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: subview

Filename: admin/_layout_main.php

Line Number: 44